# NSNotificationCenter is returning nil - Any idea why NSNotificationCenter loses value before callback?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

I have essentially the same code for two different notifications.  The first one is returning my data correctly but the second one is nil.  This may be a silly question but could it be because I'm using the same NSNotificationCenter for both?

```
NSNotificationCenter *note = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[note addObserver:self selector:@selector(onProcessedReady:) name:@"Processed" object:nil];
[note addObserver:self selector:@selector(onGeneratedReady:) name:@"Generated" object:nil];
```

This is where I am setting the data for NSNotification callback:

```
NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];

[data setObject:self.templateData forKey:@"Template"];

NSNotificationCenter *templateNote = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[templateNote postNotificationName:@"TemplateGenerated" object:nil userInfo:data];
```

<-- data looks good here.

This is the callback:

```
-(void) onGeneratedReady:(NSNotification *)note  ///  <-- note is nil
{
    if ([note.name isEqualToString:@"TemplateGenerated"])
    {
        NSDictionary *userData = note.userInfo;
        TemplateData *templateData = [userData objectForKey:@"Template"];
        NSLog(@"what is in userData?");

    }
}
```

It should be noted that the object 'self.templateData' is an object class I created.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) TemplateData *templateData;
```

Just to be sure that my object 'self.templateData' was not the problem, I tried the following and still the note returning in the callback is nil.

```
NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];    
// [data setObject:self.template forKey:@"Template"];
[data setObject:@"I am so happy" forKey:@"NotHappy"];

NSNotificationCenter *templateNote = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[templateNote postNotificationName:@"TemplateGenerated" object:nil userInfo:data];
```

data looks good here.  I have a key/value pair

```
[0] = @"NotHappy" : @"I am so happy"
  key = (__NSCFConstantString *) @"NotHappy"
  value = (__NSCFConstantString *) @"I am so happy"
```

This is the callback:

```
-(void) onGeneratedReady:(NSNotification *)note  ///  <-- note is nil
{
    if ([note.name isEqualToString:@"TemplateGenerated"])
    {
        NSDictionary *userData = note.userInfo;
        TemplateData *templateData = [userData objectForKey:@"Template"];
        NSLog(@"what is in userData?");

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is returning nil? Your code looks good, by the way. The error must be elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I just changed the note names to be two different ones and the second on is nil.  I'll update my question.

Comment: I don't get it: what is nil and when?

Comment: Show the code where you trigger both of these notifications.

Comment: where is the addObserver code for `onTemplateReady:`

Comment: The code you just posted isn't for either notification you are listening for. Show the code that posts the "Processed" and "Generated" notifications.

Comment: Is it `note` that is nil or `note.userInfo`? It's a little confusing from the question.

Comment: What makes no sense is that posting a notification with a name of "TemplateGenerated" will NOT result in the `onGeneratedReady:` method even being called. So how can the `note` be `nil`?

Comment: My bad.  In my hurried attempt to hide actual code names, I made a little mistake.

Comment: @maddy - Yes, the onGereatedReady method is getting executed.  The problem is that the (NSNotification *)note is nil.  It doesn't make any sense to me either.

Comment: OK, you should update your question with the proper names so people (like me) don't waste time look down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Real Answer !!!**

I was returning an object in NSNotificationCenter but **the object did not have a strong pointer** and I was losing my object before getting back to the callback.

I hope this post helps somebody in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

`note` is just a reference to the `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` upon which you're calling the `addObserver:selector:name:object:` method. There is no problem in using the same reference, actually you could write directly

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onProcessedReady:) name:@"Processed" object:nil];
```

It's not clear what you put in the `templateData` property, nor where you actually post the notification named *"Generated"* which notifies self and runs `-onGeneratedReady:`.

Comment: I up voted your answer because at least you answered one of my questions.  I tried naming them two different names but that didn't work.